# LibGdx Garbage Collector

Tags: android, libgdx

LibGDX Game freezing and showing this in Logcat.
And is happening on Random occasions.

```
08-27 19:32:46.015: D/dalvikvm(12024): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1205K, 22% free 6961K/8816K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-27 19:32:58.909: D/dalvikvm(12024): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1201K, 22% free 6957K/8816K, paused 22ms, total 23ms
08-27 19:32:59.089: D/dalvikvm(12024): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1180K, 22% free 6957K/8816K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
08-27 19:32:59.279: D/dalvikvm(12024): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1180K, 22% free 6957K/8816K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
08-27 19:32:59.469: D/dalvikvm(12024): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1180K, 22% free 6957K/8816K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
```

After this

```
08-27 19:32:59.469: D/dalvikvm(12024): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1180K, 22% free 6957K/8816K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
```

repeats until the application is closed.

Comment: You're probably allocating too much of something.

Comment: There isn't much we can do without further information.

Comment: I am not able to understand what other part of code should I post.

Comment: I am loading 18 1sec sound files+4 Bitmap Images and I am disposing the textures.

Comment: I hope you are loading the textures only once?

Comment: I was loading texture only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is Fixed. The Problem was in the code. The game was going into one infinite loop hanging the game.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error message. I don't know what your game is and how you make new allocations, but at some point your garbage collector needs to run to open up free space for new objects. Check all allocations, debug your application and try to find where exactly it gets stuck.

Sometimes a functional app does not mean that it uses the memory effectively. Check your allocations and try to reduce the amount you are using. (This is what you should do even if the app works correctly.) Searching the project and putting a breakpoint at lines that contain the keyword "new" is a good start.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html) is the official memory debugging tutorial.